# Java not found.Please make sure the system environment variable JAVA_HOME points to Java version 1.8 or higher

Tags: java, pingfederate

I am trying to install PingFederate but which alerts with Java not found.Java is installed properly please help me to install without issues.

**Alert comes on PingFederate Installation:**

> Java not found.Please make sure the system environment variable `JAVA_HOME` points to Java version 1.8 or higher.

**Commant prompt Java installation check:**

```
PS C:\Users\S_TEST> java -version
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
```

**Environment Variables:**

JAVA_HOME

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101
```

PATH

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;
            %SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```

Comment: try the following: `JAVA_HOME c:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_101`

Comment: what does `echo %JAVA_HOME%` on your CMD gives you?

Comment: @djames  echo %JAVA_HOME% gives %JAVA_HOME%, but variable is set and I restarted the system once.

Comment: if the variable is set, then echoing it would show the value.

Comment: How are you setting the environment variable? If it is set through command line it will be lost when session closes. Set it as a user variable (recommended) or as system variable in System Properties dialog.

Answer (score 0):

How are you executing PF? Command-line or as a Service? If you are running via run.bat (command-line), then you'll need to exit your terminal shell after each change to JAVA_HOME. You can also try adding "\bin" to your JAVA_HOME setting per the instructions here --> https://documentation.pingidentity.com/pingfederate/pf82/index.shtml#gettingStartedGuide/task/installingJava.html

Answer (score -3):

I think you might be running 32 bit executable of your software on 64 bit machine having 64 bit jdk installed.I had same issue with android studio and then I executed "studio64.exe" instead of "studio.exe".
You might need to look installation directory of your software (which you are installing) for a 64 executable.:))

Comment: studio.exe is 32 bit executable of android studio and studio64.exe is 64 bit executable.

Comment: for me installed java is 64 bit installed inside C:java/program files, so this is correct, right?

Comment: Which version of windows are u using not edition.find it by opening command prompt and there u will get windows version

Comment: Is is installed in c:\java\program files ?

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101

Comment: Last option You can download any small software (eg. Bluej as far i can remember )that need jdk and if it work fine then there is problem with ur software